# Equivalence of universal closure of formulas and implication

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Prove/Disprove: If $A^{\forall}$ is logically equivalent to $B^\forall$ (that is, any structure $M$ and assignment $\rho$ satisfies $A^\forall$ if and only if it also satisfies $B^\forall$), then either $A\to B$ or $B\to A$ is true (satisfied in any structure/assignment).

My intuition says it's false, as I think $A^\forall$ and $B^\forall$ can be equivalent in that for some assignments $A$ fails and $B$ is true while for others $B$ fails and $A$ is true, which would mean neither $A\to B$ nor $B\to A$ are true, but I'm stuck on this for a long time unable to find a suitable counter example...

Answer (score 1):

As my previous answer was wrong, this will instead be an explanation to why it was wrong and what was the correct answer.

> I assumed that the truth value of the individual formulas of
>   $A^\forall$ must be the same as those of $B^\forall$ since $A^\forall$
>   is satisfied if and only if $B^\forall$ is satisfied.

However, consider the case in which a single non quantified formula of $A^\forall$ is false. Now, since $A^\forall$ is false iff $B^\forall$ is false, there must be at least one false formula in $B^\forall$ .

For the case in which there is only one, the truth values of the formula (1) could be that of (3) and the values of (2) those of (4) .

$A\rightarrow B\tag{1}$

$B\rightarrow A\tag{2}$

$F\rightarrow T\tag{3}$

$T\rightarrow F\tag{4}$

In such a case (1) is true while (2) is false. Hence the truth value of the individual formulas of $A^\forall$ need not be the same as those of $B^\forall$ .

The statement (5) however, is still true, since at least one of either $A→B$ or $B→A$ has to be true; because the same $B$'s and $A$'s are used.

> either $A→B$ or $B→A$ is true $\tag{5}$

Comment: I understand your point, but I am still uncertain as to why there is no structure and assignment where $A^\forall$ and $B^\forall$  are both false, where neither $A\to B$ nor $B\to A$ hold (as $A$ is true for some assignment for which $B$ is false and vice versa)

Comment: The definition of implication $A\rightarrow B$ is $\lnot A\lor B$ . So If $A$ and $B$ are both false, then the implication is true. 

There is no assignment of true values where $A→B$ and $B→A$ are both false. One will always be true as per the definition of implication in logic.

Comment: And by the question, it is defined that both $A$ and $B$ always have the same assignment of truth value. If this was not part of the question, you would be right in saying that $A\rightarrow B$ could be true when $B\rightarrow A$ is false.

Comment: For a single assignment and structure, one of $A\to B$ and $B\to A$ will be true, but the question is if one of $A\to B$ or $B\to A$ is just true (for all assignments and structures), so if for one assignment $A\to B$ is true and $B\to A$ is false, and for another $A\to B$ is false and $B\to A$ is true, this does not solve the question (well, it does, as a counter example..)

Comment: also, $A$ and $B$ are not defined to have the same truth value, the existential closure of $A$ and $B$ were defined to have the same value.

Comment: $A$ must have the same truth value as $A^\forall$, because $A^\forall$ is only true when every non-quantified formula of $A$ is true.

Comment: But what if $A^\forall$ is not true? Then it can be that for some assignments $A$ is true and for others $A$ is not true..

Comment: You are indeed correct. I have edited my answer to explain my mistakes, and arrive at the correct answer.